# Apache camel jcr

Tags: apache-camel, jcr

I am new to camel as well as JCR's.
I am trying to connect to Liferay's content repository using the JCR component in Camel. What I am trying to achieve is pass a content id explicitly and using Camel, I want to hit the content repository of Liferay and retrive the relevant data.

I am trying my hands at the fuse IDE tool as well to get this done.

What I have managed to do so far is configure the endpoint uri to hit my repository. Not sure how to proceed further. Havent found much info on implementations
with Camel JCR.

Any pointers will be of great help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Did you have chance to check out [this wiki page](http://camel.apache.org/jcr.html)?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your inputs, I had been referring to that for some progress so far. I am sorry but due to my lack of knowledge, I am stuck as to how to use "CamelJcrGetById" operation or any operation for that matter in camel-context.xml, my spring interface. Since I am using Fuse IDE for the implementation,I can see how I can pass the values for uri field from my properties window. Where do I pass the operation value?

Comment: When you use "CamelJcrGetById", you should set the id into the message body as a String, camel-jcr producer will take the id from the message body.

Comment: I tried doing that. I gave the Id value in the Id field in the properties window. However I seem to be getting the following error:"The value '13702' of attribute 'id' on element 'from' is not valid with respect to its 
 type, 'ID'." I am not sure why it is complaining. I believe the content id is of type Id only.

Comment: I just checked the code of JcrProducer, it is using the Session.getNodeByIdentifier(String id). and the ID should be string.